# how i press a picturebox more than one time c# visual studio

Tags: c#, picturebox

I need to know if I can press a picturebox two times or more in the same run time to do a function as many time as the user want ? 
I mean that to run the method more than one time
"Click action in my program occur in the first time i click and i want it to be every time the picture box is clicked. "

```
 private void img1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //... 

 }
```

I try to but it runs in the first press only 
Any suggestions?

Comment: The Click event shall occur every time the control is clicked upon. You'll have to share more of your code to get an answer. What does your event handler do, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Click action will occur every time picture box is clicked. But if you are asking about different methods like doing something on click and something different on double click then you can define 2 different methods for click and doubleclick.

Comment: no , Click action in my program occur in the first time i click and i want it to be every time the picture box is clicked.

Comment: do you have a sample code or something? because click action should work everytime button is clicked, unless you are setting enabled to false, or trying to do something static. for example making the picture's width=100.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do call some function for every time he clicks and the UI needs to be uninterrupted, you may want use [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Here is a sample hope that is what you want. And please elaborate on your question.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ThreadStart(YourFunction).BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }


    private void YourFunction()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        MessageBox.Show("YourFunction called!");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , i will try to understand your point :) , i dont now why you use the Thread,sleep here but i will read more about it :)

Comment: Thread.sleep() was just a dummy call which will simply wait for 5 seconds. ignore that thread.sleep i wanted to show some function that would take time so did that.